# List of Strings in a Grails domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to have a `List` of `String` that works in MySql in a Grails domain class.

I have tried the following:

```
class Catalogue {

List books
String book
static hasMany = [books: book]

}
```

and

```
class Catalogue {

List books

}
```

and

```
class Catalogue {

String[] books

}
```

and

```
class Catalogue {

ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>()

}
```

The last three compiles but the entry is not present in MySQL.
There is no table, or column to represent this data in MySQL and I have tried populating the array with data. Still nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `hasMany`. Furthermore you need to define `books` as a `List` since without it you would get a simple `Set` that does not allow any duplicates.

```
class Catalogue {
    static hasMany = [books: String]
    List books
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: It would help if you improved this answer. The system automatically flagged it as being of low quality.

Comment: please elaborate on your answer to explain what the code does and how it solves the problem. This will help others in the future who see your answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a domain Book class:

```
class Book {
 String title
 String isbn
 ...

String toString(){
  return "${title}" 
 }
```

}

and modify your Catalogue as

```
class Catalogue{
  String name
  ....
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
  //etc etc 
}
```

Comment: `static hasMany` does the jobs (see answer above)