# How to get only one value of a String that have set some values in grails and is not a list?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have one column in my database that have this values "Bob;Steve;Fred". This column is a String (not a list) and I want to be able to build a query that give me the value that I'm pass throught the params.

This is my domain:

```
String name (values that contain name is: Bob;Steve;Fred)
```

That I'm trying to do is build a query that only get me the name that I pass in the method:

This is the My method and that I'm trying to do:

```
def updateName(String myName) {
    MyDomain md = MyDomain.findByName(myName)
    if (!md) {
       log.warn "name not found [" + name+ "]"
    }

}
```

With this, I'm getting always `md = null`;

That I want is, for example. If I pass myName=Bob that I want is find Bob in my string name that have three names (Bob;Steve;Fred):

```
 MyDomain md = MyDomain.findByName(Bob)
 md should be = Bob
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem, but it should be `findByName`, not `findByname`

Comment: also. What this _String name (values that contain name is: Bob;Steve;Fred)_ means? Give exact examples of passed values and domain values and what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi @Mikelis. I've update my question. Please take a look. But, basically that I want is get the name that I pass in the arg, match with my string store in the data base and return the value

Comment: you are trying to create a new Object, not retrieve existing one?

Comment: retrieve the existing one. My existing string have this values:  "Bob;Steve;Fred". If I pass like arg Bob in my method, I want that if match get the name

Comment: I think you need to change your domain model to split these out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**INTRO**
Although there is one answer for existing problem, as @tim_yates pointed out, there are possible problems with using my answer as well as Your approach of setting the domain class is not the best 

**How to set list in domain** 
Grails domain classes has [hasMany selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672310/list-of-strings-in-a-grails-domain-class), so your domain class should look like this:

```
class MyDomain {
    static hasMany = [names: String]
    List names
}
```

**How to add a name** 
When having a domain object and wanting to add another name to the list, you can use `myDomainObject.addToNames(thename)` 

**How to retrieve by name** 
As I stated before, this requires createCriteria() :

```
def results = MyDomain.createCriteria().list{
    "in"("names",someName)
}
```

This will return a list of all domain objects. If you want to get some data from them, you can loop through using `each` and refer to one item using `it`:

```
results.each{
    println it.names
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These default functions like `findBySomething()` work only with exact values. Because they are translated to Hibernate queries and in the query it checks is the value of object is equal to the passed value. 
**But** Grails has a thing called [criteria](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) and if I understand correctly (that you want domain value that INCLUDES your passed String), you should go like this:

```
def results = MyDomain.createCriteria().list{
    ilike("name", "%"+myName+"%")
}
```

**ALSO** 
I don't get what you are trying to achieve, but this structure doesn't seem good (to store possible values in a string like that)

Comment: Thanks Mikelis, Sorry, I think that this could work, but I'm getting a object in results not the name like a string that I'm trying to match

Comment: The above would also find false positives where `name = 'timus;kate;bobina'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this too:

MyDomain md = MyDomain.findByName("%" + myName + "%")

Check the doc: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html

Comment: This does not work if The word list includes a word with another word in it. I.E ""Joshua, James, Jimmy". Searching for Josh and Jim will also return this. And it's incorrect